# SLES 11 - slapd is spamming the syslog

Tags: openldap, sles11, slapd

How do I get slapd to quiet down?
Every second it's writing the same five lines to the /var/log/messages file.

```
May 24 13:16:09 servername slapd[21299]: conn=5866 op=15204 SRCH base="" scope=0 deref=2 filter="(objectClass=*)"
May 24 13:16:09 servername slapd[21299]: conn=5866 op=15204 SRCH attr=subschemaSubentry namingContexts altServer supportedExtension supportedControl supportedFeatures supportedSASLMechanisms supportedLDAPVersion vendorName vendorVersion
May 24 13:16:09 servername slapd[21299]: conn=5866 op=15204 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
May 24 13:16:09 servername slapd[21299]: conn=5866 op=15205 SRCH base="o=od,c=us" scope=2 deref=2 filter="(|(|(|(|(cn:dn:=global)(cn:dn:=standards))(objectClass=organizationalUnit))(objectClass=organization))(&(&(objectClass=*)(cn:dn:=00026))(ou:dn:=dev)))"
May 24 13:16:09 servername slapd[21299]: conn=5866 op=15205 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=45 text=
```

These don't seem to be error messages to me.  AFAIK, ldap is working fine.
The openldap.org docs showed that I could add "loglevel 0" to slapd.conf, but that didn't help.

Any ideas how I can get this thing to shut the heck up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have search logging turned on. Turn off debugging.

You may need to edit `/etc/sysconfig/openldap` as well.

Comment: "loglevel 0"??  Already tried that.

Comment: Post the output of: `tr "\0" \  < /proc/\`pidof slapd\`/cmdline`

Comment: /usr/lib/openldap/slapd -h  ldap://127.0.0.1:389   -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -u ldap -g ldap -o slp=on od

Comment: "loglevel 0" didn't work, so I had to mess around with some other values.  32768 didn't turn it off.  129 seems to have help alot.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Check to see if you have any other `loglevel` lines set in a similar configuration file. It may be additive.

Answer (score 2):

> Any ideas how I can get this thing to shut the heck up?

Many ways! Unconsciousness is perhaps the most absolute. Gags may also be effective.

For a more useful answer, consider filtering those messages: [Is there a way to filter syslog entries?](https://serverfault.com/questions/15106/3139)

Comment: I do like this idea and will probably make use of it elsewhere.  But I think it's more direct to put the gag right in the talker's mouth, rather than put plugs in my ears.  :)