# Excluding clients from web logs?

Tags: nginx, logging

Is it possible to exclude certain IP addresses from Nginx's *access.log*, for example where lots of the requests come from a monitoring server?

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. I think you are wanting to block connections rather than screw with what is being logged. Look into allow and deny blocks.

Comment: It does make sense. I don't think it's possible though. You can however create a file which is only accessed by your monitoring server and disable access_log on that via a location block

Comment: Similar question: https://serverfault.com/questions/15106/is-there-a-way-to-filter-syslog-entries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built in filtering to do this.
If possible you can point your monitoring server to a special file and do it like this:

```
location /monitoring.php {
  access_log off;
}
```

Comment: I don't think I'd want to do this.  Because what if the monitoring service becomes compromised, you'd never know.  Not wise.  Instead, consider log management, and then you can filter out the dross, and only display the log entries when the logs change from the usual state.

Comment: @TomO'Connor fair point, you could also only allow access from the monitoring IP, listen on a different IP, etc. But all of this kind of misses the point: You usually want to monitor your user facing application just like a user would use it. All of this is just work arounds.

Comment: I'd rather log all the things, and filter before display, rather than drop logs because they're a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you the same but slightly different:

```
location /monitoring.php {
  access_log monitor.log;
}
```

- separate location for monitoring
- separate monitoring log file

This gives you the advantage of separating the monitoring entries from the real production logs but still you have everything at hand if needed.